# How to install postgresql 9.3 dB in RHEL7 without using YUM utility

Tags: linux, postgresql, installation

I need to install postgresql 9.3 dB in my azure cloud instance which is Rhel 7.6 machine, there is no internet connection.  I can download the required rpm file and ftp to the VM.

How to install without using yum command.

Could you please provide me the complete step by step procedure.

Comment: If you have rpm package manager installed then you can install by `rpm -i <package_name>`. Check the rpm [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm)

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should install a current version (e.g. 9.6, 10 or 11). You can download the RPMs manually from here: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/ or for unsupported versions from here: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/archive/

Comment: Thank you so much a_horse_with_no_name. It would be a very big help to me. In addition, could you please provide me the procedure to follow, high level steps also enough. Thanks again 